# How to replace certain position after match using sed in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sed, redhat

I have a line I want to replace such as

```
'baseurl' => 'https://231.231.231.231'
```

But I only want it to replace the https://231.231.231.231 part.

Basically I want it to be

```
'baseurl' => 'myvaluehere'
```

I have tried `sudo sed -i "s|'baseurl'|${value1}|g" file.php`

How do I replace after certain characters after 'baseurl' is matched?

Comment: `s/x\(y\)z/p\1q/` : `xyz` → `pyq`

Comment: @jhnc im sorry, could you elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E "/(baseurl'[^']*')[^']*/s//\1myvaluehere/" input_file
'baseurl' => 'myvaluehere'
```

Comment: Hi, this looks great, is there a way to substitute my variable $value1 into the myvaluehere and still work?

Comment: @meteorb372 Sure. `sed -E "/(baseurl'[^']*')[^']*/s//\1$value1/" input_file`

Comment: hmm, i'm getting ```sed: -e expression #1, char 36: unknown option to `s'``` , I have tried adding curly brackets too but to no avail

Comment: @meteorb372 Does your variable contain the `/` char? If so, it conflicts with `sed`s default delimiter and will need to be changed. Try this if that is the case `sed -E "/(baseurl'[^']*')[^']*/s~~\1$value1~" input_file`

Comment: my god, you are a lifesaver! I have been trying out all sorts of combinations, thank so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you can achieve it:

1. find the match
2. exclude it
3. find the next pattern and replace it

And here is a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) version since have not used `sed` so much:

```bash
perl -lpe "s/'baseurl' => \K'http[^ ]+/'XYZ'/g" <<< "'baseurl' => 'https://231.231.231.231'"
'baseurl' => 'XYZ'
```

- `'baseurl' => \` find the match
- `\K` exclude it (= ignore it for substitution)
- `'http[^ ]+` match this part and replace it -- *the assumption is that there is no space in the url*
- `'XYZ'`
- `<<<` is a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) feature and means **String Here** which provides input for `perl` , or:

  - `echo "string" | perl -lpe ...`, also can be
  - `perl -lne ... file.txt`

Since we use double quotes `"` in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) we can use variables as well:

```bash
VAR=XXYYZZ
perl -lpe "s/'baseurl' => \K'http[^ ]+/$VAR'/g" <<< "'baseurl' => 'https://231.231.231.231'"
'baseurl' => XXYYZZ'
```

Comment: great suggestion, i am restricted to sed only, sorry!